# Makefile PHONY/ALL target: only builds the first

Tags: makefile

```
FC=gfortran

perf.c.bin: perf.c
    $(CC) -std=c99 -O3 $< -o $@ 

perf.f90.bin: perf.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -O3 $< -o $@

all: perf.c.bin perf.f90.bin
.PHONY: all
```

If I run just `make`, it just builds the `perf.c.bin`. If I run `make all`, it builds both `perf.*.bin`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default target is the *first* target, not the one named "all". If you want your "all" to be the default (so that `make` is equivalent to `make all`) then just put it first.